Would bloodsucking syringiform creatures need an anticoagulant to feed?
I am brainstorming creatures to use in my 'alien' (I think it will just be a very tiny world on Earth) world project. One I am calling syringiforms for now. As the name implies are creatures that have the physiology and appearance of syringes. Also like syringes, they are piercing-suckers, and while some have herbivorous diets, most consume blood.
Would syringiforms need to have some kind of anticoagulant spit or whatever to be successful, or are they built in a way to not need it? I figured that since anticoagulants are not need for legit syringes, the same applies here as they feed just as quickly as drawing blood would take.
While this is an exotic world, I will say that my aliens' blood can clot at a reasonable rate. Do I need to give syringiforms anticoagulants, or can they feed just fine without them?

So... mosquitoes? Which do have anticoagulants. Have you done research on blood eating animals?

Yeah, but I reckoned that if syringes can do it without it, maybe they can too. @GaultDrakkor

If you are referring to getting blood for blood tests, I believe all  the ampules have some stuff in them that includes anticoagulants- they are needed at some point to keep the blood in a usable state. Hole size in a hypodermic needle is very wide compared to a mosquito mouth parts. Needle width has implications of how much the victim notices a bite.

"If syringes can do it without it, maybe they can too." No offense, but just because your mosquitos look like syringes doesn't mean they have anything at all in common with syringes, which are inanimate and synthetic. Are your aliens inanimate and synthetic? How large are these aliens? If they're large enough, they don't need anticoagulants... but they'd also need to feed on elephants due to the amount of blood they'd need. This feels like you're putting the cart before the horse. I recommend designing the creatures first (like size...) and asking about anticoagulants second.

LOCATION LOCATION LOCATION
As the comments have pointed out, there is a massive similarity with your syringiforms and earth mosquitos: both blood-sucking lifeforms using piercing 'attacks' to feed. For the sake of this answer I'll draw another comparison: vampire bats. Also a blood feeding animal with a completely different approach, but able to sustain a much larger size.
The reason both of these animals 'work' is because they have an appropriate approach for their size. The mosquito can sting anywhere on skin and the anticoagulants make sure the blood that flows in between the cells can be sucked up. The vampire bat makes an incision and uses the blood's natural flow to lick it from the wound.
This brings us to syringes, which don't do either. To get any kind of blood flow at acceptable speed, syringes have to be inserted directly into the vein. Realistically, for a syringe life form to always be able to reach its victims vein would be unachievable, not to mention nearly useless for a herbivorous diet.
Which leaves only the option to sting at any location on skin and using the natural blood flow at that location as intake. In which case, yes, anticoagulants are definitely needed. However, this raises another issue, the tip of the needle and intake hole is very small, and the blood flow would be insufficient to get an acceptable amount in a short amount of time. It doesn't have the small blood requirement of the mosquito due to its size, nor the surface area of attack of the vampire bat. Therefore the time taken is significantly larger and, on top of anticoagulants, I would imagine it would also need either a numbing or paralytic agent to allow for enough time with the victim.
Alternatively you'd have to redesign the attack needle entirely to allow for things as serration and/or multiple intake holes. In which case it needs to be tapered to deal with the increasing blood flow, and would less and less resemble actual syringes, on top of the increased damage and trauma to the victim.
Conclusion: Yes, anticoagulants are likely needed. However, they alone are unlikely to be sufficient for the survival of these species.
